# iPhone UITableView overlaps UITabBar When Displaying it as a Subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, interface-builder

I have a Custom TabViewController that adds subviews to the current view depending on what `UITabBarItem` is selected. For the different subviews I have simulated a Navigation Bar and a Tab Bar so that the sub views match the format when they are displayed. The one sub view, which contains a UILabel, displays fine however the sub view with the UITableView overlaps the UITabBar. However in the Interface Builder I have sized the UITableView to not cut off the UITabBar.

**Adding the subview in the TabViewController**

```
[self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];
```

[image: SubView in the interface editor]
[image: SubView on the Emulator]

Comment: Are you using the IB or code for the views ? Seems like you are using both !

Comment: I am using IB just changing the controllers in the code

Comment: If that is the case, then you would not need this. `[self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];` If they are properly connected in the IB, that should do.

Comment: It is a custom TabViewController which extends UIViewController inorder to be able to push it onto the navigation stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to be sure, but I think you are adding the table view to the wrong view. Assuming that `self` is your UITabBarController subclass, you are adding the custom view in the view that covers the entire screen, including the tab bar.

Instead, you should be adding the custom views to the selected view controller's view:

```
[self.selectedViewController.view addSubview:subViewController.view];
```

This will limit the stuff you are adding to the tab bar controller's content area, and won't overlap the tab bar.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this approach, though: it seems like it would make more sense to add subViewController to the set of view controllers that the UITabBarController manages, rather than messing around with the view hierarchy.

Also, there is nothing inherently wrong with loading views from a nib and then manipulating them in code. "Mixing styles" is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Legolas stated, it seems like you are mixing styles here. Given that it sounds like you need to push it from the code, you could try full instantiation of the object from the code, for example:

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
table.delegate = self; //or whatever the delegate is
table.dataSource = self; //or wherever the datasource is
```

...then add it to whatever view you need to.

If that all fails, double check your nib and make sure you have the proper options set for whether a tab bar is being shown, nav bar, etc, as that will effect the size.